# PyTorch, apply different functions element-wise

Tags: python, pytorch

I defined a tensor like this

```py
t_shape = [4, 1]
data = torch.rand(t_shape)
```

I want to apply different functions to each row.

```py
funcs = [lambda x: x+1, lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x-1, lambda x: x*2]  # each function for each row.
```

I can do it with the following code

```py
d = torch.tensor([f(data[i]) for i, f in enumerate(funcs)])
```

How can I do it in a proper way with more advanced APIs defined in PyTorch?

Comment: What do you mean the APIs defined in pytorch?

Comment: @zihaozhihao I mean APIs can do it without for loop as I did in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your solution is good. But it won't work with any tensor shape. You can slightly modify the solution as follows.

```
t_shape = [4, 10, 10]
data = torch.rand(t_shape)

funcs = [lambda x: x+1, lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x-1, lambda x: x*2]

# only change the following 2 lines
d = [f(data[i]) for i, f in enumerate(funcs)]
d = torch.stack(d, dim=0)
```